# Lucene 6.4.1 special character equal sign "=" not escaped by QueryParser.escape(...)

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working with lucene 6.4.1 and get an exception with an input which is containing an equals sign "=":

```
Caused by: INVALID_SYNTAX_CANNOT_PARSE: Syntax Error, cannot parse =:  
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.generateParseException(StandardSyntaxParser.java:1030)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.jj_consume_token(StandardSyntaxParser.java:912)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.Clause(StandardSyntaxParser.java:462)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.ModClause(StandardSyntaxParser.java:279)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.ConjQuery(StandardSyntaxParser.java:210)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.DisjQuery(StandardSyntaxParser.java:180)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.Query(StandardSyntaxParser.java:133)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.TopLevelQuery(StandardSyntaxParser.java:114)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser.parse(StandardSyntaxParser.java:62)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.core.QueryParserHelper.parse(QueryParserHelper.java:245)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.StandardQueryParser.parse(StandardQueryParser.java:159)
```

I know there is a was to escape lucene special characters with

```
QueryParser.escape(...)
```

but why not the equal sign?
I'm looking for a flexible way to not escape it by any self written code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the flexible StandardQueryParser ([org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.StandardQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html)), but are escaping using the classic QueryParser ([org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html)). The equal sign is not part of the classic QueryParser syntax, and so is not escaped by `QueryParser.escape`

Comment: is there a way to escape special characters with StandardQueryParser?

Comment: There is a QueryParserUtil  [org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.QueryParserUtil](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/queryparser/index.html?org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html) but this class does not care about the equal sign either.